# Does iPhone API allow to application to capture system events, like new message, new email, new push, etc.?

Tags: ios, events

My app needs to activate, or at least be able to something on the system event, like new message, or new email/etc. Is it possible? If not -- any possible workarounds?

Comment: Without backgrounding for AppStore apps, any solution is impractical.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can do that.
Option 1 - register a custom URL scheme and then e-mail a link. The iPhone will start your app with the link when the user clicks on it.

Option 2 - Use the Apple Push Notification Service.